# Is there a multi-threaded download manager with no thread limit?

Tags: downloads

I use dispatch-proxy to club multiple IPs and on windows IDM uses that to get me great speeds. About 2-3 MB/s. My college limits speed per local IP so I assigned multiple IPs to the same adapter and got a boost. I prefer ubuntu over windows, but I need a download manager which can ideally let me decide the number of segments per download so I can utilize all possible bandwidth I can get. Even aria2c limits me at 16 connections per download and others have generally just 10.
I really need this fix as nothing is worse than slow internet.

Comment: where do you see the 16 connections limit (axel or aria2c)?  additional maybe you can try multiget.

Answer (score 0):

`axel` apparently does. From [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/axel.1.html):

```
--num-connections=x, -n x
      You can specify an alternative number of connections here.
```

Comment: Only 16 but, i was looking for something with no limit.